# How to use a class that is in the referenced project of a referenced project?

Tags: c#

I have 3 projects: projectA, projectB, projectC.

projectA references projectB.

projectC references projectA.

projectB has a public TestClass class.

Can I create a TestClass object in projectC without projectC having a reference to projectB? (projectC already has a reference to projectA which has a a reference to projectB)

Comment: No, TestClass does not exist in projectA or projectC, only in projectB. Any project that needs to instanciate an object of TestClass must reference projectB.

Comment: Extract it to ProjectD and then refer B to D and C to D.

Comment: No, you need direct reference fom C to B (assuming that you don't want reflection scenario).

Comment: are you familiar with `Encapsulation` in regards to your Classes access modifiers `public class, private class static class etc..`

Answer (score 0):

You can't because it's Project-to-Project reference. It's looking only in the referenced project it can't see connections beyond that.

You can read more about the references [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx).